# How to use autocomplete with models in MVC 5

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, autocomplete

```
@model alina1617.Models.DropDownModel


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Menu";
}

<h2>Groepen</h2>
<div>


<select id="@Html.IdFor(m => m.selectedItem)" name="@Html.NameFor(m => m.selectedItem)">
    @foreach (var groepModel in ViewBag.groepen)
    {
        <option value="@groepModel.id" title="@groepModel.Beschrijving" class="groepitem">@groepModel.Naam</option>
    }
</select>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#selecteditem').autocomplete({

        });

    })
</script>
```

So how exactly can I use autocomplete when filling a selectlist? My models get passed using a viewbag and I use a foreach to iterate through them and create all the options. How can I utilize autocomplete when it's not just a list of String values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use selectize

http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-For-Custom-Tags-Input-Select-Box-selectize-js/examples/

or you can also used select2

https://select2.github.io/examples.html

let me know it is helpful or not